# UBUNTU VM lost DHCP and IP

Tags: virtualization, vmware, dhcp, ip

Running UBUNTU on vmware workstation over Windows 10 as a host.

slyubski@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Created VM with BRIDGED network itf. 
UBUNTU by default installs itself with DHCP.

After installation tested networking:
    ip addr
    ping
    browser

Later installed numerous packages.

Today figured out that networking is lost:
   no IP address, no DHCP client running.

After reboot DHCP client is running but no IP address and no default gateway.
NOTE. The windows host works just fine.

Here is UBUNTU after reboot - NO IP, DHCP client is running but it is not clear if it sends
any DCHP requests.

BTW the WIFI router who is the local DHCP server has the max number of 50 clients.
We have:

5 laptops
   2 tablets
   2 phones
   1 printer
   1 TV

overall 11 clients.
VM becomes the client #12.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you very much.
Sergey Lyubskiy